# Inclusão de método na classe própria

Tags: orientação-a-objetos

Imagine um `sistema OO` que tenha pelo menos 2 `classes`:

```
Admins.php
Clientes.php
```

Na vida real, isto é, no sistema, clientes não podem se cadastrar. Nesse caso, a função de cadastrar o Cliente é do `administrador.`

A dúvida é: onde eu devo incluir o `método` `cadastrarCliente($Cliente)`?

Na Classe Admins ou na Classe Clientes?

Estou fazendo assim:

Clientes.php

```
 class Clientes {

     private $idCliente;
     private $nome;
     private $documento;
     private $senha;
     private $endereco;
     private $numero;
     private $complemento;
     private $bairro;
     private $estado;
     private $cidade;
     private $cep;
     private $email;
     private $telefone;
     private $celular;
     private $bloqueado;

     public function __construct( 
         $_nome,  
         $_documento, 
         $_senha, 
         $_endereco, 
         $_numero, 
         $_complemento, 
         $_bairro, 
         $_estado, 
         $_cidade, 
         $_cep, 
         $_email, 
         $_telefone, 
         $_celular, 
         $_bloqueado
    )
     {
         $this->nome = $_nome;
         $this->documento = $_documento;
         $this->senha = $_senha;
         $this->endereco = $_endereco;
         $this->numero = $_numero;
         $this->complemento = $_complemento;
         $this->bairro = $_bairro;
         $this->estado = $_estado;
         $this->cidade = $_cidade;
         $this->cep = $_cep;
         $this->email = $_email;
         $this->telefone = $_telefone;
         $this->celular = $_celular;
         $this->bloqueado = $_bloqueado;
     }

     public function setIdCliente ($_idCliente){
         $this->idCliente = $_idCliente;
     }

    public function getIdCliente () {
        return $this->idCliente;
    }

    public function getNome () {
        return $this->nome;
    }

    public function getDocumento () {
        return $this->documento;
    }

    public function getSenha () {
        return $this->senha;
    }

    public function getEndereco () {
        return $this->endereco;
    }

    public function getNumero () {
        return $this->numero;
    }

    public function getComplemento () {
        return $this->complemento;
    }

    public function getBairro () {
        return $this->bairro;
    }

    public function getEstado () {
        return $this->estado;
    }

    public function getCidade () {
        return $this->cidade;
    }

    public function getCep () {
        return $this->cep;
    }

    public function getEmail () {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function getTelefone () {
        return $this->telefone;
    }

    public function getCelular () {
        return $this->celular;
    }

    public function getBloqueado () {
        return $this->bloqueado;
    }

}
```

ClientesDao.php

```
 class ClientesDao {

     private $conexao;

     public function __construct ($_conexao) {      
         $this->conexao = $_conexao;
     }

     public function bloquear ($idCliente, $bloqueio) {      

         $string = "UPDATE clientes SET bloqueado = '".$bloqueio."' WHERE idCliente = ".$idCliente;

         $this->conexao->query($string);

     }

     public function excluir ($idCliente) {      

         $string = "DELETE FROM clientes WHERE idCliente = ".$idCliente;

         $this->conexao->query($string);

     }

     public function cadastrar ($cliente) {      

         $string = "INSERT INTO clientes (nome, documento, senha, endereco, numero, complemento, bairro, estado, cidade, cep, email, telefone, celular, bloqueado) 
                    VALUES (
                       '".$cliente->getNome()."',
                       '".$cliente->getDocumento()."',
                       '".$cliente->getSenha()."',
                       '".$cliente->getEndereco()."',
                       '".$cliente->getNumero()."',
                       '".$cliente->getComplemento()."',
                       '".$cliente->getBairro()."',
                       '".$cliente->getEstado()."',
                       '".$cliente->getCidade()."',
                       '".$cliente->getCep()."',
                       '".$cliente->getEmail()."',
                       '".$cliente->getTelefone()."',
                       '".$cliente->getCelular()."',
                       '".$cliente->getBloqueado()."'
                       )";

         $this->conexao->query($string);

     }

     public function ultimoIdCadastrado () {         
         return $this->conexao->insert_id;
     }

     public function editar ($cliente) {         

         $string = "UPDATE clientes 
                    SET 
                      nome = '".$cliente->getNome()."', 
                      documento = '".$cliente->getDocumento()."', 
                      senha = '".$cliente->getSenha()."', 
                      endereco = '".$cliente->getEndereco()."', 
                      numero = '".$cliente->getNumero()."',
                      complemento = '".$cliente->getComplemento()."', 
                      bairro = '".$cliente->getBairro()."', 
                      estado = '".$cliente->getEstado()."', 
                      cidade = '".$cliente->getCidade()."', 
                      cep = '".$cliente->getCep()."', 
                      email = '".$cliente->getEmail()."', 
                      telefone = '".$cliente->getTelefone()."', 
                      celular = '".$cliente->getCelular()."', 
                      bloqueado = '".$cliente->getBloqueado()."' 
                    WHERE 
                      idCliente = ".$cliente->getIdCliente();

         $this->conexao->query($string);
     }


     public function alteraSenha ($senha, $idCliente) {
         $string = "UPDATE clientes SET senha='".$senha."' WHERE idCliente = ".$idCliente;
         $this->conexao->query($string);
     }

     public function pesquisaClienteId($idCliente) {
         $cliente = null;           

         $string = "SELECT idCliente, nome, documento, senha, endereco, numero, complemento, bairro, estado, cidade, cep, email, telefone, celular, bloqueado 
                    FROM clientes 
                    WHERE idCliente = ".$idCliente;

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;      

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0)
         {

             list ($idCliente, $nome, $documento, $senha, $endereco, $numero, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cidade, $cep, $email, $telefone, $celular, $bloqueado) = $registros->fetch_row();             

             $cliente = new Clientes($nome, $documento, $senha, $endereco, $numero, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cidade, $cep, $email, $telefone, $celular, $bloqueado);                     
             $cliente->setIdCliente($idCliente);
         }

         return $cliente;

     }

     public function pesquisaClienteDocumento($doc) {

         $string = "SELECT idCliente
                    FROM clientes 
                    WHERE documento = '".$doc."'";

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;      

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0)
         {
             return true;
         }

         return false;

     }

     public function pesquisaClienteEmail($email) {

         $string = "SELECT idCliente
                    FROM clientes 
                    WHERE email = '".$email."'";

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;      

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0)
         {
             return true;
         }

         return false;

     }

     public function pesquisaClienteNome($nomeCliente) {
         $cliente = null;           

         $string = "SELECT idCliente, nome, documento, senha, endereco, numero, complemento, bairro, estado, cidade, cep, email, telefone, celular, bloqueado 
                    FROM clientes 
                    WHERE nome = '".$nomeCliente."'";

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;      

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0)
         {

             list ($idCliente, $nome, $documento, $senha, $endereco, $numero, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cidade, $cep, $email, $telefone, $celular, $bloqueado) = $registros->fetch_row();
             $cliente = new Clientes($nome, $documento, $senha, $endereco, $numero, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cidade, $cep, $email, $telefone, $celular, $bloqueado);                     
             $cliente->setIdCliente($idCliente);
         }

         return $cliente;

     }

     public function pesquisaNomeCliente($idCliente) {
         $cliente = null;           

         $string = "SELECT nome FROM clientes WHERE idCliente = ".$idCliente;

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows;      

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0)
         {

             list ($nome) = $registros->fetch_row();
             $cliente = $nome;
         }

         return $cliente;

     }

     public function pesquisaClientes() {
         $Clientes = null;           

         $string = "SELECT idCliente, nome, documento, senha, endereco, numero, complemento, bairro, estado, cidade, cep, email, telefone, celular, bloqueado FROM clientes";

         $registros = $this->conexao->query($string);
         $quantasLinhas = $registros->num_rows; 

         if ($quantasLinhas > 0) {

             while (list ($idCliente, $nome, $documento, $senha, $endereco, $numero, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cidade, $cep, $email, $telefone, $celular, $bloqueado) = $registros->fetch_row()) {

                 $cliente = new Clientes($nome, $documento, $senha, $endereco, $numero, $complemento, $bairro, $estado, $cep, $cidade, $email, $telefone, $celular, $bloqueado);                     
                 $cliente->setIdCliente($idCliente);

                 $Clientes[] = $cliente;
             }
         }

         return $Clientes;

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Carlos, cadastrarCliente($Cliente) dentro da classe admins faz sentido imaginando que é uma página ou ação da controladora Admins. Seria também uma organização mais atrelada ao `diagrama de casos de uso` do padrão UML, onde esse método seria exclusivo do ator Administrador.

Answer (score 0):

Métodos descrevem comportamentos dos objetos que o possuem. Se o comportamento de cadastrar cliente é inerente ao administrador, o mesmo deveria possuir o método. Apesar disso, é interessante desacoplar as regras de negócio de POJOS. O ideal mesmo seria que você tivesse outro objeto para gerenciar o cadastro de clientes (e.g. ProcessadorCliente). Esse processador seria ativado pelo administrador, garantindo assim que o cadastro seja feito apenas por eles.

Comment: Adicionei os códigos para ver se fica mais claro.